# Django django_suit : how to create two-level menu?

Tags: django, menu, admin

Django 2.2, django-suit==0.2.26
This is more django_suit question rather then django.

I have a flat menu defined in my `settings.py`, each item is a link in admin view:

```
SUIT_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN_NAME': 'MyAdminName',
    'MENU': (
        'sites',
        '-',
        {
         'label': 'MenuItem1',
         'url': SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view1',
        },
        {
         'label': 'MenuItem2',
         'url': SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view2',
        },
        {
         'label': 'MenuItem3',
         'url': SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view3',
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make it work as two level menu that opens on mouseover.

It can be easily done for the application's models like this:

```
SUIT_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN_NAME': 'MyAdminName',
    'MENU': (
        'sites',
        '-',
        {'app': 'MyApp',
         'label': 'MenuLabelTopLevel',
         'models': ('MyModel1', 'MyModel2', 'MyModel3')
        }
    }
}
```

When I position the mouse over MenuLabelTopLevel, I get a dropdown with `'MyModel1', 'MyModel2', 'MyModel3'`.

I am looking for the syntax that would allow me to have the same functionality for any arbitrary list of views in my application, something line this:

```
SUIT_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN_NAME': 'MyAdminName',
    'MENU': (
        'sites',
        '-',
        {'app': 'MyApp',
         'label': 'MenuLabelTopLevel',
         'link_list': (SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view1',SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view2', SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view3')
        }
    }
}
```

Does this functionality exist in `django_suit`? The docs do not have an example for this. If not, maybe some similar django package (that would allow me to do it in my existing admin menu, not to create some new menu at the top of the page)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that. No new keyword is needed, you just stick those into "models" as list of "label and url" key-value dictionaries.

```
SUIT_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN_NAME': 'MyAdminName',
    'MENU': (
        {'label': 'MenuLabelTopLevel', 
            'models': [
                {
                    'label': 'SubMenuItem1',
                    'url': SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view1',
                },
                {
                    'label': 'SubMenuItem1',
                    'url': SCRIPT_NAME + '/some_view1',
                 }
            ]
        }
    )
```

Just one minor inconvenience: separator ( `'-'` ) is ignored in the list of those second-level items.